# PowerShell script to exclude a list of computers from getting disabled in AD

Tags: powershell

Could you guys please help me with the following scenario . Here is what i am trying to accomplish .

1. I generate a report of computers that need that need to be disabled in AD = file1.txt
2. I have a pre-made list of Computers to exclude
   from getting disabled = file2.txt
3. I have a script to disable a list
   of computers from a text file but i would like to exclude whatever
   computer that exist in the file2.txt .

Here is what i have so far

```
$toBeDisabled = Import-CSV \\SERVER\file1.csv
```

$toBeExcluded  = Import-CSV \SERVER\file2.csv

$toBeDisabled = $toBeExcluded | Where-Object {($toBeExcluded | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -NotContains $_.Name}

ForEach ($Computer in $toBeDisabled.DeviceName)

{ 
    $Computer = $Computer.Trim()

```
$ADComputer = Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties Description
```

If ($ADComputer)

{ 
Add-Content c:\temp\computers.log -Value "The following PC $Computer has been found and disabled"

Set-ADComputer $ADComputer -Description "$($ADComputer.Description)- Disable due to inactivity - $(Get-Date) - by $env:UserName " -Enabled $False

}

Else

{ Add-Content c:\temp\computers.log -Value "$Computer not Found in Active Directory or Was disabled before"

}

}

Im getting the following error (Select-Object : Property "Name" cannot be found)

Thanks

Comment: You are ambiguous. Without knowing the file1.?txt ?csv and file2 layout it's difficult to help.

Comment: @LotPings . I have csv file1 ( computers that will get disabled ) , the file2.txt notepad ( computers that i want to be excluded if it exists in file1.csv . both files have computers ( ex: PC-678789 )

Comment: At least `file1.csv` seems to have the header `DeviceName` - this is what I call layout. It's your task to include such information in your edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out .

Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -Property "DeviceName" | 
    Where SideIndicator -eq "<=" |
    Select DeviceName | 
    Export-Csv "\Server\DisableList.csv" -NoType

Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here would be to just compare these two files first:

```
$toBeExcluded = Import-Csv C:\temp\file2.csv
$toBeDisabled = $toBeExcluded | Where-Object {($toBeExcluded | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -NotContains $_.Name}
```

The above assumes that `file2.csv` has the same format (so it has property `Name`).

Then, instead of `$Computers` you just have to use `$toBeDisabled` in `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks for info , unfortunately i have your suggestion but i got the following error (Select-Object : Property "Name" cannot be found.) . I have update the above code to reflect all what i have so far .

Comment: You'll have to post the format of `file2.csv` or just change `Name` to name of column where you have computer names. If it's standard list you'll have to use `Get-Content` instead of `Import-Csv`. That's all I can tell based on info you provided.